# Multiple clients are connected even if we call accept once

Tags: c++, sockets

Server-side Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define SOCK_PATH "./server.sock"

int main() {
    // Create a socket
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create socket." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the server socket address
    sockaddr_un serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serverAddress.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    // Bind the socket to the server address
    int bindResult = bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (bindResult == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to bind socket to address." << std::endl;
        close(serverSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    // Listen for incoming connections
    int listenResult = listen(serverSocket, 1);
    if (listenResult == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to listen for connections." << std::endl;
        close(serverSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Server is listening for connections..." << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        // Accept a client connection
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (clientSocket == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to accept client connection." << std::endl;
            close(serverSocket);
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "Client connected." << std::endl;

        // Receive data from the client
        char buffer[1024];
        int bytesRead = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (bytesRead == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to receive data from client." << std::endl;
            close(clientSocket);
            close(serverSocket);
            return 1;
        }

        // Process the received data
        std::cout << "Received data from client: " << buffer << std::endl;

        // Close the client socket
        close(clientSocket);
    }

    // Close the server socket
    close(serverSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

Client-Side Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define SOCK_PATH "./server.sock"

int main() {
    // Create a socket
    int clientSocket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create socket." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the server socket address
    sockaddr_un serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serverAddress.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    // Connect to the server
    int connectResult = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (connectResult == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to server." << std::endl;
        close(clientSocket);
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "client connected successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    int clientSocket2 = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket2 == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create socket." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } 


    // Set up the server socket address
    sockaddr_un serverAddress2;
    serverAddress2.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serverAddress2.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    // Connect to the server
    int connectResult2 = connect(clientSocket2, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress2, sizeof(serverAddress2));
    if (connectResult2 == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to server." << errno << std::endl;
        close(clientSocket2);
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "client connected successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
   /* // Send data to the server
    const char* message = "Hello, server!";
    int bytesSent = send(clientSocket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    if (bytesSent == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to send data to server." << std::endl;
        close(clientSocket);
        return 1;
    } */

    // Close the client socket
    close(clientSocket2);
    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, server-side will call accept() once as my client-side is not sending data to server. Even though accept() is called once, both the client sockets are connected. But If I add delay/sleep (I have commented) between listen and accept, only one client is connected and other fails with 61 error which I am expecting even in this case where there is no sleep between listen and accept.

How to fix this issue where multiple clients are connecting even though accept() is called once and listen() also has backlog 1 other than adding random delay?

Comment: In short: your understand what backlog does is wrong. It does not limit the number of total connections but only the number of *pending* connections, i.e. where no `accept` was called yet. Apart from that the number given to backlog is only a suggestion, the actual limit used by the OS may differ.

Comment: Also, there's platform specific behavior.  Linux: _"The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with Linux 2.2. Now it specifies the queue length for completely established sockets waiting to be accepted, instead of the number of incomplete connection requests. The maximum length of the queue for incomplete sockets can be set using `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog`. When syncookies are enabled there is no logical maximum length and this setting is ignored. See tcp(7) for more information."_

Comment: I agree backlog is just a hit. But I am calling accept once. So only one connect should be successful. By the way, how come adding sleep between listen and accept is resolving the issue.

Comment: You're calling `accept` in a while loop, so you'll call it mulitple times (once each time it loops).  The loop only exits if it gets an errror on an `accept` or `recv`, which should be rare.

Comment: In my case, I am not calling accept multiple times and recv is blocking and client is not sending data. Whichever client got connected first recv will wait till client gets disconnected.

Comment: @saiteja2894 The code you posted calls `accept()` in a loop. How is that not 'multiple times'? And why are you closing the server socket and exiting just because *one client* doesn't send any data? This is poor quality code. NB This is [tag:c++] code, not [tag:c] code. Don't tag indiscriminately.